# how I can implement default product in each category in mvc4 using routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes

how I can implement default product in each category in mvc4 using routing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to set up your routes like this:

```
 routes.MapRoute("Category Route", 
                 "categories/{category}/{product}", 
                 new { 
                     Controller = "Categories", 
                     Action = "ShowCategory", 
                     Category = "Books", 
                     Product = ""
                 });
```

Then, your controller action method could look like this:

```
public CategoriesController : Controller {
    public ActionResult ShowCategory(String category, String product) {
        // rest of code goes here
    }
}
```

Then inside your action you can design your repository to check **String.IsNullOrEmpty(product)** and determine the default one based on a database flag or however you want to indicate that.